# date_format time with ":" produces warning

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb, date-format

having a query like this (on a MariaDB 5 database):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(mov.date), '%H:%i') AS time
FROM ek_movement mov
```

displays an error / warning in phpmyadmin query editor saying, it has added a closing bracket for me.
The cause of that is obviously the char ":", separating the hours from the minutes. I`ve noticed that executing queries with that issue takes much longer compared to executing a query where no such error / warning appears (for example, by changing the separator character to space).
How can i fix that, is there the possibility, to escape that ":"-character? I don't want to use combinations of CONCAT to achieve what i want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the colon.

- If `date` is a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` datatype, remove the `FROM_UNIXTIME`.
- If `date` is a `BIGINT` or `INT`, keep the `FROM_UNIXTIME`.
- If `date` is a `DATE`, you will get only '00:00' or `NULL`.

Think of it this way:  For most of those case, simply selecting the column gives you something that looks like a date: `2018-07-18 22:07:21`, so `DATE_FORMAT()` makes sense to act on it.

But for `INT`, a value like `1531976939` clearly needs some kind of conversion before it can be treated like a date, hence the need for `FROM_UNIXTIME()`.

Comment: In my case, mov.date is of datatype INT. Having the warning / info message about the missing closing bracket slows down the query a lot. Thanks for your info, but it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @whocares81 - there must be something _adjacent to_ the query that we can't see.  The parentheses look fine; there are no brackets or braces in that SQL.

Comment: i've copied and pasted the query in phpmyadmin sql "editor" and the warning / error is gone. If I copy the original query (which is much longer) and execute it the same way, the warning / error is gone, too. I'm sorry, i have no idea how this can happen.